# Path way from Values to XML in android studio

Tags: android, arrays, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to find the pathway from the XML folder in Android Studio to the Values folder which holds my list-array that I'm going to enter as the "entries" array, but I can't seem to figure it out, please help!

```
    <ListPreference
    android:title="Units"
    android:defaultValue=""
    android:entries=""
    android:summary=""
    ></ListPreference>
```

Comment: Is it a string array? If it is then it should be in @string/whatever_you_named_it

Comment: Oh, okay, didn't know that you were supposed to set it to string, thanks for the help and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Just give the path to the array file like this @array/whatever you named the array

eg @array/pref_units_options